# How to Reload page after Range Slider stopped sliding by Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Range Slider for price, based upon min and max price in slider i have display products... i want reload page with min and max value, after Range slider stopped sliding, but my Jquery reloading in every slide... but to reload page after Range Slider stopped sliding

My jQuery

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
           var amtmin, amtmax;
           $(function () {
               $("#slider-range").slider({
                   range: true,
                   min: 1,
                   max: 10,
                   values: [2, 8],
                   slide: function (event, ui) {
                       $("#amount").val("Rs. " + ui.values[0] + " - Rs. " + ui.values[1]);

                       amtmin = ui.values[0];
                       amtmax = ui.values[1];

                   }
               });
               $("#amount").val("Rs. " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - Rs. " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

               amtmin = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
               amtmax = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

           });

           //alert("Url : " + finalUrl);
           if (amtmin!=null && amtmax!=null)
           {
                var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { categoryId = 4 })';
                var finalUrl = url + "?price=" + amtmin + "-" + amtmax;
                window.location.href = finalUrl;
           }

        </script>
```

Slider

```
<p style="padding: 10px 0px 20px 10px;">
            <label for="amount"> Price range: </label> 
            <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
        </p>
        <div id="slider-range">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to Stop Event for reloading page after Range Slider Stopped,

Final JQuery i

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           var amtmin, amtmax;
           $(function () {
               $("#slider-range").slider({
                   range: true,
                   min: @from,
                   max: @To,
                   values: [@from, @To],
                   slide: function (event, ui) {
                       $("#amount").val("Rs. " + ui.values[0] + " - Rs. " + ui.values[1]);

                       amtmin = ui.values[0];
                       amtmax = ui.values[1];

                   },
                   stop: function(event, ui) {

                            var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { categoryId = @catId })';
                            var finalUrl = url + "?price=" + amtmin + "-" + amtmax;
                            window.location.href = finalUrl;

                            }
               });
               $("#amount").val("Rs. " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - Rs. " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

           });

        </script>
```